# Why I can't see the value in my trackbar?

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv

my running environment as follow:

Mac OSX EI 10.11.5

opencv 2.4.13

Xcode Version 7.3.1

why there is not display my value on the trackbar as attached picture.

is this because of system problem?

```
main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); 

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Thresholded Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Control"

    int iLowH = 0;
    int iHighH = 179;

    int iLowS = 0;
    int iHighS = 255;

    int iLowV = 0;
    int iHighV = 255;

    cvCreateTrackbar("LowH", "Thresholded Image", &iLowH, 179); 
    cvCreateTrackbar("HighH", "Thresholded Image", &iHighH, 179);

    cvCreateTrackbar("LowS", "Thresholded Image", &iLowS, 255);
    cvCreateTrackbar("HighS", "Thresholded Image", &iHighS, 255);

    cvCreateTrackbar("LowV", "Thresholded Image", &iLowV, 255); 
    cvCreateTrackbar("HighV", "Thresholded Image", &iHighV, 255);

    while (true)
    {
        Mat imgOriginal;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
            break;
        }

        Mat imgHSV;

        cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV

        Mat imgThresholded;

        inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image

        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
        dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );

        dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );

        namedWindow("Thresholded Image", 0);
        namedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

        resize(imgThresholded,imgThresholded, Size(imgThresholded.cols/3, imgThresholded.rows/3));
        namedWindow("Thresholded Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded); //show the thresholded image

        resize(imgOriginal,imgOriginal, Size(imgOriginal.cols/3, imgOriginal.rows/3));
        namedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Original", imgOriginal); //show the original image

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[this is running display window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJz7D.png)

Comment: If someone has a solution for getting the trackbar value next to the trackbar in MacOS X, please do post it.